# Intuition behind the definition of a maximal operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

A linear operator $A:D(A)\subset H \to H$ on a Hilbert space $H$ is maximal monotone (AKA m-dissipative) if

1. $A$ is monotone, that is $\Re(Ax,x) \leq 0$ for all $x \in D(A)$
2. Range$\{I-A\} = H$

My question is what is the intuition, implication, or the need behind maximality? Also why wouldn't we only check
$$\text{Range}\{A\} = H$$
without the identity?

Comment: Out of curiosity, in what context did you come across this definition? Are you doing optimization?

Comment: No it was in the context of PDEs. The defintion is given in Brezis's book Ch 7.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer, but below is some additional context from convex optimization which might be helpful.

In convex optimization, finding $x$ that minimizes a convex function $f$ is equivalent to finding $x$ such that
$$
\tag{$\clubsuit$} 0 \in \partial f(x).
$$
The subdifferential $\partial f$ is a great example of a monotone operator. Notice that
$$
\tag{$\spadesuit$} 0 \in \partial f(x) \iff x \in (I + \partial f)(x).
$$If $f$ is lower semicontinous as well as convex, it can be shown that for any $y \in \mathbb R^n$ there is a unique $x$ such that
$$
y \in (I + \partial f)(x).
$$
Since $x$ exists and is unique, it makes sense to say $x = (I + \partial f)^{-1}(y)$.
Returning to equation ($\spadesuit$), we can see that
$$
x = (I + \partial f)^{-1}(x).
$$
This suggests solving equation ($\clubsuit$) using the following fixed point iteration:
$$
x^+ = (I + \partial f)^{-1}(x).
$$
This famous iteration is called the "proximal point method".
The operator $(I + \partial f)^{-1}$ is called the "proximal operator" of $f$.

For a general monotone inclusion problem
$$
0 \in F(x)
$$
the analogous statement is that if $F$ is maximal monotone then for any $y \in \mathbb R^n$ there exists a unique $x$ such that $(I + F)(x) = y$. (This is "Minty's theorem".)
Since $x$ exists and is unique, it makes sense to say that
$$
x = (I + F)^{-1}(y).
$$
The operator $(I + F)^{-1}$ is called the "resolvent" of $F$ (in the context of convex optimization, at least). Noting that
$$
0 \in F(x) \iff x \in (I + F)(x) \iff x = (I + F)^{-1}(x)
$$
suggests solving $0 \in F(x)$ via the proximal point iteration
$$
x^+ = (I + F)^{-1}(x).
$$

To assume that a set-valued function $F$ is monotone is analogous to assuming that a function $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ is convex. To assume that $F$ is maximal monotone is analogous to assuming that a function $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ is convex and lower semicontinuous.